# How can I turn this DataFrame into a DataFrame with average score by Index Value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below DataFrame, with wine variety, reviewer and score.  I'd like to make a new DataFrame that outputs variety as the column labels and lists the average score by reviewer and variety.  Simply stated I'd like to output a DataFrame with variety at the top and reviewer as the index with the average score by reviewer and variety.  I've tried several things, and I can't get it to work.

The actual information I will be a lot more reviewers with a lot more varieties, but I wanted to provide a simplified version.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Variety": ['Cabernet', 'Pinot', 'Cabernet', 'Pinot', 'Pinot', 'Cabernet', 'Pinot', 'Cabernet'],
               "Reviewer": ['Bill', 'Sally', 'Bill', 'Sally', 'Bill', 'Sally', 'Bill', 'Sally'],
               "Score": [90, 85, 87, 93, 80, 81, 93, 88]})
```

Comment: you should post what you would like your expected output to be, as well as any code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More like a `pivot` problem

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index='Reviewer',columns='Variety',values='Score',aggfunc='mean')
Out[29]: 
Variety    Cabernet      Pinot
Reviewer                      
Bill      87.000000  87.666667
Sally     84.666667  93.000000
```

Comment: Wen the pandas jedi :P

Comment: @jdgalaway yw : -) if this solve your problem , you can consider accept it ? check mark at the right

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby, calculate means and pivot the results:

```
df.groupby(['Variety', 'Reviewer']).mean() \
                                   .reset_index() \
                                   .pivot(index='Reviewer', columns='Variety')
                Score      
Variety  Cabernet Pinot
Reviewer               
Bill         88.5  86.5
Sally        84.5  89.0
```

The first line calculates the means and the last line reshapes the dataframe appropriately. The second line is necessary to get the output of `.mean()` in the proper shape for the `pivot()` function.

**Step-by-step**:

```
df.groupby(['Variety', 'Reviewer']).mean()
                  Score
Variety  Reviewer       
Cabernet Bill       88.5
         Sally      84.5
Pinot    Bill       86.5
         Sally      89.0

df.groupby(['Variety', 'Reviewer']).mean().reset_index()
        Variety Reviewer  Score
0  Cabernet     Bill   88.5
1  Cabernet    Sally   84.5
2     Pinot     Bill   86.5
3     Pinot    Sally   89.0
```

which we can now transform from 'long format' to 'wide format' with `pd.pivot()` and get the result at the top of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Reviewer', 'Variety']).mean()
                   Score
Reviewer Variety
Bill     Cabernet   88.5
         Pinot      86.5
Sally    Cabernet   84.5
         Pinot      89.0
```